# How to remove a "zombie" framework from an Xcode/Swift build

Tags: xcode, swiftui, app-store-connect

I developed a small SwiftUI app that uses FMDB as a framework. I've done this with several other apps in the past and encountered no problem. With this one, I ran into the problem that though it would run on my test devices and the simulator, it failed App Store upload with a message that signing the FMDB framework failed (using "embed and sign" option; this is a problem for another question, for sure). After lots of frustrating research and unsuccessful trial-and-error attempts, I decide to remove the FMDB framework and bring in the FMDB source, so I could get it to the App Store.

That seemed to work, as I can upload the app to the App Store and run it on simulators, but when I run the app on a device, I get the message, **"dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FMDB.framework/FMDB"** and accompanying stuff. I can find no remaining reference to the FMDB framework, but obviously Xcode can. I've cleaned the build folder, deleted derived data, deleted the app from the devices for a fresh install, cursed and moaned, and tried multiple devices.

Any ideas where to look to remove references to the FMDB framework? Ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: You say you can't find a reference. Where did you look? Did you look in build phases? Also are you using pods?

Comment: Using Carthage. No reference anywhere in build phases.

Comment: If you open up the project in a non-Xcode editor (TextMate) for example, does a global search of the entire project directory for "FMDB.framework" reveal anything?

Comment: I did that, and found references in project.pbxproj (along with references to another framework I had removed). Deleting those references made no difference.

Comment: You might need to quit Xcode and clear the cache (DerivedData).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've quit Xcode and cleared derived data many times, with no change. Some years ago I encountered a situation in which Xcode was accessing an older build and I wonder if there isn't something like that going on here (another thing I noticed yesterday is that a change to the launch screen did not appear when the app runs on a device). I cannot, of course, remember how I fixed it. For the present, I went back to using the FMDB framework, re-entered and updated everything, and got an app that I can upload to the App Store. So for now, I'm letting this problem lie.